# Docker local registry : push fails

Tags: docker, centos6, docker-registry

I'm trying to setup a local docker registry, but I get in troubles when trying to push images to it. I opened a github issue too: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12405

**ENVIRONMENT**

OS: CentOS 6.6

Kernel: 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64

Docker version:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
```

I'm behind a corporate proxy (http://domain\username:password@proxy:port).

**PROBLEM**

I'm launching the Docker daemon with this command:

```
sudo docker -d --insecure-registry 127.0.0.1:49500&
```

I've downloaded the config_sample.yml file from docker-registry github, renamed it to registry_config.yml, and just modified the "storage_path" in the local flavor (in order to point to a chosen directory where I want to mount a volume):

```
local: &local
<<: *common
storage: local
storage_path: /image
```

To start the registry (version 0.9.1), I open another tab in my terminal and I use that command:

```
sudo docker run -t -i -p 127.0.0.1:49500:5000 -v $HOME/localRegistry/image:/image -e DOCKER_REGISTRY_CONFIG=$HOME/localRegistry/registry_config.yml --name registry registry /bin/bash
```

Back on the 1st terminal tab, I then try to push a random image into the local registry, and this is where I get some errors:

```
$sudo docker push 127.0.0.1:49500/centos:7
INFO[1215] POST /v1.17/images/127.0.0.1:49500/centos/push?tag=7
INFO[1215] +job push(127.0.0.1:49500/centos)
INFO[1215] +job resolve_repository(127.0.0.1:49500/centos)
INFO[1215] -job resolve_repository(127.0.0.1:49500/centos) = OK (0)
invalid registry endpoint "http://127.0.0.1:49500/v0/". HTTPS attempt: unable to ping registry endpoint https://127.0.0.1:49500/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://127.0.0.1:49500/v2/: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49500: connection reset by peer
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://127.0.0.1:49500/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49500: connection reset by peer. HTTP attempt: unable to ping registry endpoint http://127.0.0.1:49500/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://127.0.0.1:49500/v2/: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49500: connection reset by peer
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://127.0.0.1:49500/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49500: connection reset by peer
INFO[1215] -job push(127.0.0.1:49500/centos) = ERR (1)
ERRO[1215] Handler for POST /images/{name:.*}/push returned error: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://127.0.0.1:49500/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49500: connection reset by peer
ERRO[1215] HTTP Error: statusCode=500 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://127.0.0.1:49500/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49500: connection reset by peer
FATA[0000] Error: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://127.0.0.1:49500/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49500: connection reset by peer
```

Ask me if you want some more specific details. Thanks for your attention :)

**UPDATE**

I had not noticed, but since I've upgraded from Docker 1.4.1 to 1.5.0 yesterday, it seems like docker wasn't able to reach the hub through the proxy (sudo docker search was failing). I fixed that by exporting HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environement variables, and by launching the daemon with sudo -E.

Then, as SGer pointed out, I wasn't throwing my config file into the registry container. Thus, the registry couldn't access the config. I changed that by moving the config file into its own directory, and by mounting that directory as a volume when running the registry container. The new running command:

```
sudo docker run -t -i -p 127.0.0.1:49500:5000 -v $HOME/localRegistry/image:/image -v $HOME/localRegistry/configDir:/configDir -e DOCKER_REGISTRY_CONFIG=configDir/config.yml --name registry registry /bin/bash
```

After those 2 modifications, I tested again, running docker daemon with -D option this time. Here is the output (split into 3 parts):

https://gist.github.com/ekeryelleven/9714312c45b7ff21ce2a

I launched the registry container (from another terminal tab): https://gist.github.com/ekeryelleven/b9bfa50bfe3221798659

Then, I pushed: https://gist.github.com/ekeryelleven/80f8f1d1dad00b0fbea9

**UPDATE 2**

Somebody told me it was possibly linked to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9315

I tried to reproduce:

```
$ wget -O- --post-data='' 'http://127.0.0.1:49500/images'
--2015-04-16 11:01:42--  http://127.0.0.1:49500/images
Resolving <proxy>... <ip>
Connecting to <proxy>|<ip>|:<port>... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 504 Gateway Timeout
2015-04-16 11:01:42 ERROR 504: Gateway Timeout.
```

So I thought maybe the proxy was messing up things when I'm trying to reach local registry, so I ran again my 1st test without setting any proxy config for the docker daemon (no HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables, no sudo -E). Output (3 parts):

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XaJaSsWk

Launching the registry container: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1tux468H

Pushing: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LsvNfdQf

Comment: I haven't used any config files with the registry yet, but it seems like you're setting the configpath to a file that's on your host, not in your container. As it's an environment variable, I'd expect that you can only set it to a file that's accessible inside the container, because it cannot access the host file system.

Comment: I've read again the documentation concerning the config file, and you're right, it has to be accessible to the container by mounting it in a volume. But I've just realized that I have another problem : since I've upgraded Docker from 1.4.1 to 1.5.0, I can't access the docker hub through my proxy. This is probably the cause of my problem.

Comment: I've updated the stuff man, taking your idea into account

Comment: My knowledge about docker isn't that big yet, sorry, I only saw that little thing. I'd suggest asking in the docker irc channel if you don't get an answer here :)

Comment: Well, I'm quite impressed you found that issue whitout having a lot of knowledge in that field! (I'm a newcomer too ha ha). Also, I've opened a github issue in the same time, to get in touch with the Docker community about that problem

Comment: For anybody else coming along to read this, when OP mentions upgrading to Docker client v1.6 and Registry 2.0, this is the best answer if you're not already on these versions or later. Per Docker's devs, work on earlier version of the registry has basically gone into maintenance mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer, but I upgraded to Docker 1.6 and Registry 2.0 and the problem disappeared.